# How to get all child data on nested firebase data in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I want to display all(nested) Firebase Realtime database data based on User id from Firebase Auth. I use Flutter Android.

My database is like this:

[image]

And my code is about like this:

home.dart

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<Todo> _dataList;

  final FirebaseDatabase _database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;

  StreamSubscription<Event> _onTodoAddedSubscription;
  Query _todoQuery;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _dataList = List();
    _todoQuery = _database.reference().child(widget.userId);
    _onTodoAddedSubscription = _todoQuery.onChildAdded.listen(_onEntryAdded);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _onTodoAddedSubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  _onEntryAdded(Event event) {
    setState(() {
      _dataList.add(Todo.fromSnapshot(event.snapshot));
    });
  }

  Widget _showTodoList() {
    if (_dataList.length > 0) {
      return ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: _dataList.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            String todoId = _dataList[index].key;
            bool status = _dataList[index].status;
            int datetime = _dataList[index].datetime;
            double current = _dataList[index].current;
            double voltage = _dataList[index].voltage;
          });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _showTodoList(),
    );
  }
}
```

and my model class:

todo.dart

```
class Todo {
  int datetime;
  double current;
  double voltage;
  String key;
  bool status;
  String userId;

  Todo(this.datetime, this.userId, this.status, this.current, this.voltage);

  Todo.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot snapshot)
      : key = snapshot.key,
        status = snapshot.value["status"],
        datetime = snapshot.value["datetime"],
        current = snapshot.value["current"],
        voltage = snapshot.value["voltage"];

  toJson() {
    return {
      "status": status,
      "datetime": datetime,
      "current": current,
      "voltage": voltage,
    };
  }
}
```

I've done that.

But, what if I change database to something like this (add nested child): 
[image]

How to get all child data based from user id Firebase auth?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: no answer yet, anyone know?

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @Farhana no, i just change my database structure, to make it more simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When structuring the database, you need to take into account that it has to be flat structure. If you change the structure to your second image, then you can do the following:

```
final FirebaseDatabase _database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
User currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

var ref = _database.reference().child(currentUser.uid);
ref.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){
   print(snapshot.value);
   print(snapshot.key);
    snapshot.value.forEach((key,values) {
         print(values);
   });
});
```

Here first get an instance of the database and get the currently login user, then using `once()` you can fetch the data, to be able to access the fields that are nested then you have to use `forEach()` to iterate inside the `datasnapshot`.